# How to split these two strings consistently?

Tags: python, regex, unicode

This little code is to recognize Chinese words. It works mostly but have some issues on some cases, and the first word '鱼' is such one example.

```
re_default = re.compile("([\u4E00-\u9FD5a-zA-Z0-9+#&\._%\-]+)", re.U)

words1 = re_default.split('鱼')
words2 = re_default.split('兰蔻')
```

The output is:

```
['', '鱼', ''] ['', '兰蔻', '']
```

It seems that the first word '鱼' is not in the code range defined. I want to split it the same as '兰蔻'. How to find the right range and accomodate it in the regex?

Comment: "" is in the CJK extensions B block. Your range only includes the non-extension CJK ideographs block. See the ranges for all the CJK extensions on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs).

Comment: If you just want to handle 鱼, then add `\u29f83` into your regex. If that's not what you want, you need to be clearly define what "Chinese words" are.

Comment: To split strings, you should use specialized libraries, not regex: too many special cases, and you may make it work only for a specific language (and possibly just for a region, and period of use). Unicode has an annex just for splitting strings.

Comment: @Sweeper How to modify the range to include all the CJK extension codes? I need all of CJK range.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you have only specified one of the many ranges for Chinese characters.

You can use 8-hexdigit Unicode escapes to specify the higher CJK ranges.  The ranges are listed in the [Unicode 14.0 Character Code Charts](https://unicode.org/charts/).  Below includes all the CJK unified ideograph extensions:

```py
import re

CJK = ('\u4E00-\u9FFF'          # CJK Unified Ideographs
       '\u3400-\u4DBF'          # CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A
       '\U00020000-\U0002A6DF'  # CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B
       '\U0002A700-\U0002B73F'  # CJK Unified Ideographs Extension C
       '\U0002B740-\U0002B81F'  # CJK Unified Ideographs Extension D
       '\U0002B820-\U0002CEAF'  # CJK Unified Ideographs Extension E
       '\U0002CEB0-\U0002EBEF'  # CJK Unified Ideographs Extension F
       '\U00030000-\U0003134F') # CJK Unified Ideographs Extension G

re_default = re.compile(rf'([{CJK}a-zA-Z0-9+#&._%-]+)')

words1 = re_default.split('鱼')
words2 = re_default.split('兰蔻')

print(words1,words2)
```

Output:

```
['', '鱼', ''] ['', '兰蔻', '']
```